# Angular 4 Cannot find a differ supporting object

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, bitcoin

I'm having a problem trying to bind or display some data in my app.

I want to do it like this:

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let price of prices">
{{prices.Low}}
</div>
```

I get this error when I run the app:

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '{"success":true,"message":"","result":[{"MarketName":"BTC-LTC","High":0.01242,"Low":0.01101255,"Volume":125744.75175454,"Last":0.01129999,"BaseVolume":1456.43310343,"TimeStamp":"2017-06-01T21:49:12.573","Bid":0.01126674,"Ask":0.0113,"OpenBuyOrders":1390,"OpenSellOrders":3345,"PrevDay":0.01119779,"Created":"2014-02-13T00:00:00"}]}' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

This is my code:

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { BittrexService } from '../bittrex/bittrex.service';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comprarmonedas',
  templateUrl: './comprarmonedas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comprarmonedas.component.scss']
})
export class ComprarmonedasComponent implements OnInit {

  prices: any;

  constructor(private bittrexService: BittrexService) {
    this.bittrexService = bittrexService;
  }

ngOnInit(){
  this.bittrexService.getPrices()
  .subscribe(
    data => this.prices = JSON.stringify(data)
  );
}
 }
```

`
service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { MarketViewModel } from '../comprarmonedas/datosmoneda'


@Injectable()
export class BittrexService {

  constructor(private http: Http, private marketModel : MarketViewModel) { }

  public getPrices() :Observable<MarketViewModel> {
    return this.http.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-ltc')
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }

}
```

Marketviewmodel:

```
export class MarketViewModel {
  public success : boolean;
  public message : string;
  public result : MarketListObject[];
}

export class MarketListObject {
    public MarketName : string;
    public High : number;
    public Low : number;
    public  Volume : number;
    public Last : number;
    public BaseVolume : number;
    public TimeStamp : number;
    public Bid : number;
    public Ask : number;
    public OpenBuyOrders : number;
    public OpenSellOrders : number;
    public PrevDay : number;
    public Created : number; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to iterate over an string, not an array.
In `component.ts` you have the following line of code:

```
this.bittrexService.getPrices()
  .subscribe(
    data => this.prices = JSON.stringify(data)
  );
```

And I think you meant to do this instead:

```
this.bittrexService.getPrices()
  .subscribe(
    data => this.prices = data.result
  );
```

When you turn your data into a string using `JSON.stringify`, it can't be used by `ngFor`, because a string isn't iterable. Instead, if you return `data.result`, which is an array, `ngFor` knows how to iterate over it.

Edit:
As yanbu pointed out in the comment, you have another bug in your template. Instead of:

```
<div *ngFor="let price of prices">
  {{prices.Low}}
</div>
```

You need to use:

```
<div *ngFor="let price of prices">
  {{price.Low}}
</div>
```

This is because prices is an array, which doesn't have the property `Low`, where price is an element of that array, which should contain the property `Low`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I try {{prices.Low}} I get no error but the data isnt binding on the DOM either. If I try {{prices}} I get [object Object].

Comment: Try `{{ price.Low }}`

Comment: Thanks @yanbu, good catch. I've updated the answer for you Claudio.